# Hide QComboBox inside QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

```
QComboBox *comboBox = new QComboBox(this);
comboBox->addItems(QStringList() << "item1" << "item2");
ui->treeWidget->setItemWidget(item, 1, comboBox);
```

I have used the method like the above code to add the comboBox to some itemWidget in a QtreeWidget. The appearance is not very good when the comboBox always shows.

Is there a method to hide the comboBox and it would appear again when I click that cell? Please give me some help. Thanks.

My current result:
[image]

Comment: You could show a picture of what you get.

Comment: I have added a picture. Thanks

Comment: What is it you do not like about the result?

Comment: i want to hide the border and the dropDown image before I click that cell. That means those cell would be same as the other cells in general and the comboBox would popup after I clicked that cell. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: You can do that with item delegates. An item delegate displays static content, and when an edit is triggered, replaces it with an editor widget.

Comment: Would you mind to give me more details? Thanks.

Comment: @NgClement use a delegate: http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Qt/Delegates/ComboBoxDelegate

Comment: Which function should I use to handle the edit behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

you can use css

```
QComboBox{ border:none; } 
QComboBox::down-arrow {image: url(:images/img/blank.png) }
QComboBox::drop-down { background-color:transparent }
```

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox